# How can I get $returnValue for async methods?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asynchronous, async-await

I believe there is possible to use `$returnValue` in VisualStudio watch window whenever you step over a function when debugging then it will show the value that was returned from the last method.
However, this only seems to work for non-async methods. If I try to do this on an awaited async method call, then it doesn't get populated.

Is there a mechanism to do this with async calls?

Answer (score 4):

Asynchronous methods are not your usual methods. They are state machines.

This method:

```cs
async Task Delay() => await Task.Delay(1000);
```

Will be translated to something like:

```cs
[CompilerGenerated]
private sealed class <Delay>d__0 : IAsyncStateMachine
{
    public int <>1__state;

    public AsyncTaskMethodBuilder <>t__builder;

    public C <>4__this;

    private TaskAwaiter <>u__1;

    private void MoveNext()
    {
        int num = <>1__state;
        try
        {
            TaskAwaiter awaiter;
            if (num != 0)
            {
                awaiter = Task.Delay(1000).GetAwaiter();
                if (!awaiter.IsCompleted)
                {
                    num = (<>1__state = 0);
                    <>u__1 = awaiter;
                    <Delay>d__0 stateMachine = this;
                    <>t__builder.AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted(ref awaiter, ref stateMachine);
                    return;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                awaiter = <>u__1;
                <>u__1 = default(TaskAwaiter);
                num = (<>1__state = -1);
            }
            awaiter.GetResult();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            <>1__state = -2;
            <>t__builder.SetException(exception);
            return;
        }
        <>1__state = -2;
        <>t__builder.SetResult();
    }

    [DebuggerHidden]
    private void SetStateMachine([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Nullable(1)] IAsyncStateMachine stateMachine)
    {
    }

[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableContext(1)]
[AsyncStateMachine(typeof(<Delay>d__0))]
[DebuggerStepThrough]
private Task Delay()
{
    <Delay>d__0 stateMachine = new <Delay>d__0();
    stateMachine.<>t__builder = AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Create();
    stateMachine.<>4__this = this;
    stateMachine.<>1__state = -1;
    stateMachine.<>t__builder.Start(ref stateMachine);
    return stateMachine.<>t__builder. Task;
}
```

Comment: Interesting what is Visual Studio showing in the $returnValue on yield return. IEnumerables and async state machines are similar.

Comment: You can request that feature at https://developercommunity.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/suggest